# How do i run an android project if i have this error "vt-x is disabled in the bios" and i cant changed to uefi?

Tags: android

Hi  I have developed a project for android.  I changed my computer and now I can't run my project I get this error "vt-x is disabled in the bios" but when I try to change the setting to uefi, my computer doesn't start. Any one have any idea what I can do?

Comment: Could you please provide more detail (examples?)

Answer (score 0):

In general the vt-x bios setting is different from the uefi setting.
You'd generally need to reinstall your Os (or change the boot configuration on linux) if you want to get uefi to work.
But generally to get vt-x working you don't need to do that.
Instead look for a bios setting to enable virtualization or enable hardware virtualization and try changing that.